# Value function of deep energy-based policies

Tags: entropy

I am reading the following paper:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.08165.pdf

I am stuck with one of their proofs, more precisely equation (14):

$$
H(\pi(\cdot|s))) + \mathbb{E}_{a \sim b}[Q_{soft}^{\pi}(s,a)] =
-D_{KL}(\pi(\cdot |s) || \tilde{\pi}(\cdot |s)) + log\int exp(Q_{soft}^{\pi}(s,a)) da
$$

I set:

$$
H(\pi(a|s)) = -\int  \pi(a|s)log(\pi(a|s))da \\
\mathbb{E}[Q_{soft}^{\pi}(s,a)] = \int  \pi(a|s)Q_{soft}^{\pi}(s,a)da \\
-D_{KL}(\pi(\cdot |s) || \tilde{\pi}(\cdot |s)) = \int \pi(a|s)log(\frac{\pi(a|s)}{\tilde{\pi}(a |s)}da
$$

and use the definition of
$$
\tilde{\pi}(a |s) = exp(Q_{soft}^{\pi}(s,a))
$$

In the end, I get
$$
H(\pi(\cdot|s))) + \mathbb{E}_{a \sim b}[Q_{soft}^{\pi}(s,a)] =
-D_{KL}(\pi(\cdot |s) || \tilde{\pi}(\cdot |s)) 
$$

**I do not understand where this part comes from:**

$$
log\int exp(Q_{soft}^{\pi}(s,a)) da 
$$

What am I missing?